# Laravel Grouping By date

Tags: laravel, eloquent, collect

i read some questions already posted here.But not found any solution for my requirement.
Remember this response showing check-in info about user visited a store.

Grouping the Collect

```
$this->collection->groupBy(function ($date) {
                return Carbon::parse($date->createdAt)->toDateString();
  }
```

Will returning the data grouping by date..

**response**

```
{
   "data":{
      "2021-08-31":[
         {
            "avatar":"avatars/IIa1gvCvww5K4geXJHUYTTZm2IKFoK113octfPB1.jpg",
            "name":"General Shop 15"
         },
         {
            "avatar":"avatars/IIa1gvCvww5K4geXJHUYTTZm2IKFoK113octfPB1.jpg",
            "name":"General Shop 15"
         }
      ],
      "2021-08-29":[
         {
            "avatar":"avatars/IIa1gvCvww5K4geXJHUYTTZm2IKFoK113octfPB1.jpg",
            "name":"General Shop 15"
         }
      ],
      "2021-08-20":[
         {
            "avatar":"avatars/GSDrGe8RLGXykvvsEVlWtnqRGbAOoJUuSh7WZhFc.jpg",
            "name":"XYZ Store"
         },
         {
            "avatar":"avatars/GSDrGe8RLGXykvvsEVlWtnqRGbAOoJUuSh7WZhFc.jpg",
            "name":"XYZ Store"
         },
         {
            "avatar":"avatars/GSDrGe8RLGXykvvsEVlWtnqRGbAOoJUuSh7WZhFc.jpg",
            "name":"XYZ Store"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

**But I want response look like blew..**
then grouping date will show as..

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "date":"2021-08-31",
         "data":[
            {
               "avatar":"avatars/IIa1gvCvww5K4geXJHUYTTZm2IKFoK113octfPB1.jpg",
               "name":"General Shop 15"
            },
            {
               "avatar":"avatars/IIa1gvCvww5K4geXJHUYTTZm2IKFoK113octfPB1.jpg",
               "name":"General Shop 15"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "date":"2021-08-29",
         "data":[
            {
               "avatar":"avatars/IIa1gvCvww5K4geXJHUYTTZm2IKFoK113octfPB1.jpg",
               "name":"General Shop 15"
            },
            {
               "avatar":"avatars/IIa1gvCvww5K4geXJHUYTTZm2IKFoK113octfPB1.jpg",
               "name":"General Shop 15"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already receiving the data you require.
just to fix the data in the required format loop the collection you received and
put it in a format the way you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can not modify that response on Mysql level while retrieving your data. What you can do is after you have your collection parse it and modify it accordingly. Something like this will work:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($myCollection->data as $key=>$value){
    $formattedResponse['data'][$counter]['date'] = $key;
    $formattedResponse['data'][$counter]['data'] = $value;
    $counter ++;
}
```

The output based on your json input example is:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "date": "2021-08-31",
        "data": [{
            "avatar": "avatars\/IIa1gvCvww5K4geXJHUYTTZm2IKFoK113octfPB1.jpg",
            "name": "General Shop 15"
        }, {
            "avatar": "avatars\/IIa1gvCvww5K4geXJHUYTTZm2IKFoK113octfPB1.jpg",
            "name": "General Shop 15"
        }]
    }, {
        "date": "2021-08-29",
        "data": [{
            "avatar": "avatars\/IIa1gvCvww5K4geXJHUYTTZm2IKFoK113octfPB1.jpg",
            "name": "General Shop 15"
        }]
    }, {
        "date": "2021-08-20",
        "data": [{
            "avatar": "avatars\/GSDrGe8RLGXykvvsEVlWtnqRGbAOoJUuSh7WZhFc.jpg",
            "name": "XYZ Store"
        }, {
            "avatar": "avatars\/GSDrGe8RLGXykvvsEVlWtnqRGbAOoJUuSh7WZhFc.jpg",
            "name": "XYZ Store"
        }, {
            "avatar": "avatars\/GSDrGe8RLGXykvvsEVlWtnqRGbAOoJUuSh7WZhFc.jpg",
            "name": "XYZ Store"
        }]
    }]
}
```